# How to shuffle a word list?

Tags: sort

I have a long list of sorted words that I would like to shuffle randomly.

Could it be done using `:sort` and some flag?

The list is in alphabetical order like:

```
abandon
ability
able
about
above
...
zebra
zero
zone
zoo
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help us to give you a more precise answer if you could give us an example. The sort command sort lines part of the solution is probably to convert the list of words into a list of line and vice a versa. Would it be possible to insert the example in your question?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt example added!

Comment: I understand that you have a list of words separate by a space (thanks for that). How would you like them to be sorted at the end?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt No! sorry, is one word per line! I need to improve my markdown skills too...

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I need a random sort

Comment: Good :-) and in which order you would like them to be sorted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141475/discussion-between-ranemirusg-and-vivian-de-smedt).

Comment: You could easily sort by any non-initial character, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. would render with some randomness. See help about sort with virtual column. Read the help and experiment to taste.

Comment: If you want to sort on the third character you could do `:sort /.\{2\}/` or `:sort /../` not really random but random like indeed.

Comment: @wbogacz nice workaround thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Case you are using `vi` with Linux , you can use `shuf` command to "Permute" or "Shuffle" the lines , which are the technical terms to randomize the lines.

When the whole file contains the lines , use `:%!shuf` & check the output lines.

When the lines are in Part of the file , use `:n,m!shuf` , where the lines between `n` & `m` will get reordered.

This Single line Solution is very robust.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I would:

- Select the list of words
- Insert a random number in front of each of them:

  `:'<,'>s/^/\=rand() /` or
  `:'<,'>g/./exe 'norm' 'I' . rand() . ' '`
- Reselect the list of words: `gv`
- Sort the list: `:sort`
- Reselect the list of words: `gv`
- Remove the numbers:

  `'<,'>s/\d\+ //`

### Explanation

The `g` (`global` )let you run a command on a range of line filtered by a regular expression (it is a way to have a loop)

The `norm` (`normal`) command let you simulate a list of key. It is the core of the solution to insert the numbers in front of each line.

The `exe` (`execute`) command let you compose a command using the Vim expression (I used it to get access to `rand()`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on how much "random" it must be. If poor builtin `rand()` is good enough then it becomes as simple as

```
:g/^/exe "move" rand() % line(".")
```

Otherwise, you have to write your own strong `Random()` function first.